# How to create a form in JSP and retrieve data from oracle databases?

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp

Is there anybody who can help me because I have to create the following in JSP and I have no idea in JSP??

I have to create a form in jsp. In the form we have to search with a number. It will take the number and search in two different oracle databases which will be connected with the form. After that it will retrieve the data which are needed to fill the fields which are included in form..

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DAO  and Save it on the
ServletContext Object from a Servlet then you can call that from the implicit object application and access all the method that you need.

This link shows you how manipulate the context and get and save object on it.
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-get-servletcontext-in-servlet.html